# Point after page number in sharelatex

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In Sharelatex, I'm using "fancy header" and would like to have a point displayed after the number of the page (I know it's pointless but required by my university). Any idea of how I can do that ?

[EDIT]
Here is what I used to have the result I currently have:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage}
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! We need to know your present code for fancyhdr to answer.

Comment: In particular you may want to post an [MWE](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/), a minimal yet complete and compilable example that shows what you have so far. An MWE make sure that we are all talking about the same thing and lets people test their solutions. TeX often has many ways to do similar things so it is important to know how you are doing things at the moment to offer a compatible solution. See also [Why does TeX require such elaborate MWE:s](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/). We don't want to see your entire paper/thesis, just a short example of the `fancyhdr` settings in action

Comment: Thanks for the comments, indeed its my first post. Is it enough or should I show more code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `\thepage .` what you are looking for?

Comment: Note that the code snippet is not an MWE in the sense of a compilable example of the links I showed you. It might be enough to give you an answer in this instance, but don't count on this for future (more complicated) questions.

Comment: Yes it is @samcarter. Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage .}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage .}
}
```